# Best way to have multiple instances of a program?

Tags: permissions, users, virtual-machine, docker

I want to run multiple instances of a program such as Firefox. I realize that `-no-remote` exists to let me to do that, but because I am using mozilla.cfg which is my personalized configuration file that applies to all profiles, it is not suitable for my case because I want to one profile that is free of my personalized settings for quickly testing certain websites in its intended manner (my configuration restricts lots of things that can break websites).

I believe I can run that program as another user but I'm not sure how that works given that I'm the only one with access to my own computer (i.e. do I have to log out of my session to run the program as another user? Is running it as a separate user as straightforward as running it on my account, even for a GUI application? Any caveats?

I was also thinking if Docker is the right tool for this but I'm not sure how well it preserves changes (from what I understand, an application running in Docker is like an image that can be restored to the exact state, but how well does it save a state the way a typical VM does persistently)?

Any other methods are also appreciated--I want to understand what options are available to me and how they differ from each other in terms of pros and cons as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `--new-instance` (which starts a new instance in all cases) with `-P` which allows you to select a different profile: use that once to create a clean profile, then name it on the command line and Firefox will start a new instance with that profile.